# Is the use of “scalable” or “scalability” correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following is grammatical?

> How is the scalability of method 1?
>
> How scalable is the method 1?

Comment: Generally speaking, this IT-related "jargon" use of the word *scalable* tends to treat it as an "absolute" (e.g. - *"This method is better because it's scalable, whereas that method isn't"*). Personally, I think talking about "degrees of **scalability**" is pushing things a bit too far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are a little off.

> <strike>How</strike> What is the scalability of Method 1?
>
> How scalable is <strike>the</strike> Method 1?

"Method 1" is being treated as the proper name of something. If you just mean "the first method," say it that way.

> What is the scalability of the first method?
>
> How scalable is the first method?

"Scalability" is a noun, so you ask about it with "what." If it were a person, place, or time, you would ask about it with "who," "where," or "when," respectively.

"Scalable" is an adjective, so you ask about it with "how."